# Can I toggle between XBMC and my Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: xbmc

Can I toggle between XBMC and my Ubuntu Desktop? I would like to be able to go back and forth between either....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash does the trick "\". It allows you to minimize the Kodi screen so that you can get back to your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Open `System Settings` and go to `Appearance` > `Behavior` and active `Enable workspaces`

[image: System Settings > Appearance > Behavior]

Open Kodi and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. You will move to the lower left hand workspace. Kodi is still running at the upper left hand workspace. You can go back to Kodi by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>. There are 4 workspaces by default.

Comment: Tried it doesn't work....

Comment: Found out the answer. "\" Backslash lets you minimize the Kodi window!